# Why scroll event handler does not work in useEffect react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I create a custom hook that returned scroll state of an element; But scrollHandler trigger only one time! Below is my code:

```js
import { MutableRefObject, useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const useScrollState = <TElement extends HTMLElement>(
  ref: MutableRefObject<TElement | null>,
) => {
  const [isTop, setIsTop] = useState(true)
  const [isBottom, setIsBottom] = useState(false)
  const targetRef = ref?.current
  const isScrollable: boolean =
    (targetRef && targetRef.offsetHeight < targetRef.scrollHeight) ?? false

  const scrollHandler = () => {
    if (targetRef && Number(targetRef.scrollTop.toString()) === 0) {
      setIsTop(true)
    } else setIsTop(false)

    if (targetRef && targetRef.offsetHeight + targetRef.scrollTop >= targetRef.scrollHeight) {
      setIsBottom(true)
    } else {
      setIsBottom(false)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect")

    targetRef?.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler)

    return () => {
      targetRef?.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler)
    }
  }, [targetRef])


  return {
    isTop,
    isBottom,
    isScrollable,
  }
}
```

It should get a ref object that refers to an element that we wanna know about its scroll state; What's wrong with my hook?

Answer (score 0):

`scroll` only fires if actual scrolling did happen.

So, your div needs to be smaller than its content and needs to show scrollbars.

also, the `useEffect` dependency array must be like this: `[ref]` not `[ref.current]`;

Comment: The div element's height is smaller than its content so it is scrollable and also I check ref for useEffect's dependency but it only trigger one time while I except it trigger when element is scrolling

Comment: it doesn't trigger even one time because it can't detect any scrolling functionality.

Comment: So how can I trigger it on scroll event of its target ref?

Answer (score 0):

This is div on which I am applying scroll event. I am using Tailwind and note that height of div is set to screen height.

```
<div ref={scrollRef} className="backgroundmain w-full h-screen overflow-y-scroll font-inter"> ...content_here </div>
```

This is the ref variable.

```
const scrollRef = useRef(true);
```

And here is the useEffect code.

```
useEffect(() => {
const scrollPosition = localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition');

const targetElement = scrollRef.current;

if(scrollPosition) {
  scrollRef.current.scrollTop = scrollPosition;
}

targetElement.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

return () => targetElement.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
```

}, []);

It works fine for me. I hope it works for you too. Thanks